# How to solve $(z+1)^3=-8i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a problem with this equation, I don't know what method to use. Can you show a method for the resolution? Thanks
$$(z+1)^3=-8i$$

Comment: Could you solve $x^3=8$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$(z+1)^3=-8i\iff(z+1)^3-(2i)^3=0.$$ Now use the identity $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

Use Euler's form for, $-8i = 8 e^{\frac{3 \pi}{2}i}=8 e^{(2k \pi + \frac{3 \pi}{2})i}$ for $k=0,1,2$.